# Delete rows containing values in range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I'm trying to delete the entire row on sheet "Data" if any value on column B contains values located in sheet "Backend" range `D3:E20`, the code below works if you hardcode a word as the condition but is not running on the range `getValue`, the logic should work like this but is currently not, I have looked at several questions here but only found options having a specific word or phrase hardcoded into the delete value, any opinions on what seems to be wrong with the code?

```
function deletee() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXX');
var SHEET = SS.getSheetByName('Data');
var RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
 var deletedata = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Backend').getRange("D3:E20");

 var deletee = deletedata.getValues();
 
 
var DELETE_VAL = deletee;
var COL_TO_SEARCH = 1; 
 
  
function deleteEachRow(){
  
  var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
  
  //Reverse the 'for' loop.
  for(var i = rangeVals.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH] === DELETE_VAL){
      
      SHEET.deleteRow(i+1); 
    };
  };
};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function dd() {
  var d=0;
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn());
  const vA=rg.getValues();
  const dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Backend');
  const drg=dsh.getRange('D3:E20');
  var dvs=drg.getValues().reduce(function(a,r) {a=a.concat(r);return a;},[]);
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){if(dvs.indexOf(r[1])!=-1){sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++);}});
}
```

Comment: Although I found the answer on a different post, your code is really working effectively, thank you.